# Unexpected Numerical Output when running automated script using Webdriver and Java

Tags: java, selenium

While automating our internal application, encountered an issue with displaying numerical value from excel file – automating the application using Selenium Webdriver (with Java and TestNG framework).

**Issue:**

- Numerical data is updated in an xlsx file without suffix “.0”
- However, while displaying the data in the console, these data are
  displayed as below with ".0" in suffix

*Input in xlsx file as below:*

- 24213
- 24214
- 24215
- 24216

*Output in Console:*

- Data: 24213.0
- Data: 24214.0
- Data: 24215.0
- Data: 24216.0

Below is the code snippet; could you please someone advise what makes the code to display this unexpected output.

Kindly do let know, if need any further details:

```
        int row;
        row = sheet.getLastRowNum() + 1;
        for (int i = 1; i < row; i++)
        {

            sheet.getRow(i).getCell(1).setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC);

            double data = sheet.getRow(i).getCell(1).getNumericCellValue();

            System.out.println("Data: " + data);
        }
```

*Please find the input file shared in OneDrive [[http://1drv.ms/1K7XQqO]](http://1drv.ms/1K7XQqO]_)*

Comment: There is some kind of formating wich "System.out.println" uses when is printed to console. And by the way this is default string representation of double
Check the following link:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/formatting.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are using double.

From  [JLS 3.10.2. Floating-Point Literals](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.2):

> A floating-point literal has the following parts: a whole-number part, a decimal or hexadecimal point (represented by an ASCII period character), a fraction part, an exponent, and a type suffix.

```
double data = sheet.getRow(i).getCell(1).getNumericCellValue();
```

From [Primitive Data Types](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html)

> The double data type is a double-precision 64-bit IEEE 754 floating point. Its range of values is beyond the scope of this discussion, but is specified in the Floating-Point Types, Formats, and Values section of the Java Language Specification. For decimal values, this data type is generally the default choice. As mentioned above, **this data type should never be used for precise values**.

Use rather `int`.

Answer (score 0):

There is some kind of formating wich "System.out.println" uses when is printed to console. And by the way this is default string representation of double
Check the following link:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/formatting.html